# Is it possible to have eclipse show markdown in side by side view? like vscode does?

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to have eclipse show markdown in side by side view?

[image]

like vscode does?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but with the restriction that the preview is only updated on save:

1. ***Window > Editor > Toggle Split Editor (Vertical)*** - **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>**
2. Choose on one side *Markdown Source* and on the other side *Preview*

If you would like it to be updated without saving, please [report this as a feature request to Eclipse WikiText](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Mylyn%20Docs&component=Wikitext), or even better, suggest a patch.